# approaches to design of database, which one?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database that will hold a list of transactions. There are two types of transactions, I'll name them credit (add to balance) and debit (take from balance).

Credit transactions most probably will have an expiry, after which this credit balance is no longer valid, and is lost.

Debit transactions must store from which credit transaction they come from.

There is always room for leniency with expiry dates. It does not need to be exact (till the rest of the day for example).

My friend and I have came up with two different solutions, but we can't decide on which to use, maybe some of you folks can help us out:

**Solution 1:**

3 tables: Debit, Credit, DebitFromCredit

```
Debit: id | time | amount | type | account_id (fk)
Credit: id | time | amount | expiry | amount_debited | accountId (fk)
DebitFromCredit: amount | debit_id (fk) | credit_id (fk)
```

In table Credit, amount_debited can be updated whenever a debit transaction occurs.
When a debit transaction occurs, DebitFromCredit holds information of which credit transaction(s) has this debit transaction been withdrawn.

There is a function `getBalance()`, that will get the balance according to expiry date, amount and amount_debited. So there is no physical storage of the balance; it is calculated every time.

There is also a chance to add a cron job that will check expired transactions and possibly add a Debit transaction with "expired" as a type.

**Solution 2**

3 tables: Transactions, CreditInfo, DebitInfo

```
Transactions: id | time | amount (+ or -) | account_id (fk)<br />
CreditInfo: trans_id (fk) | expiry | amount | remaining | isConsumed<br />
DebitInfo: trans_id (fk) | from_credit_id (fk) | amount<br />
```

Table Account adds a "balance" column, which will store the balance. (another possibility is to sum up the rows in transactions for this account).

Any transaction (credit or debit) is stored in table transactions, the sign of the amount differentiates between them.

On credit, a row is added to creditInfo.

On debit one or more rows are added to DebitInfo (to handle debiting from multiple credits, if needed). Also, Credit info row updates the column "remaining".

A cron job works on CreditInfo table, and whenever an expired row is found, it adds a debit record with the expired amount.

**Debate**

Solution 1 offers distinction between the two tables, and getting data is pretty simple for each. Also, as there is not a real need for a cron job (except if to add expired data as a debit), `getBalance()` gets the correct current balance. Requires some kind of join to get data for reporting. No redundant data.

Solution 2 holds both transactions in one table, with + and - for amounts, and no updates are occurring to this table; only inserts. Credit Info is being updated on expiry (cron job) or debiting. Single table query to get data for reporting. Some redundancy.

**Choice?**

Which solution do you think is better? Should the balance be stored physically or should it be calculated (considering that it might be updated with cron jobs)? Which one would be faster?

Also, if you guys have a better suggestion, we'd love to hear it as well.

Comment: Mmmm, corn job. My favorite :)

Comment: Lol sorry for the typo. It does sound kinky though.

Comment: Wait a minute.. i wrote it cron job as in timed job... someone edited it to corn! Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which solution do you think is better?

Solution 2.  A transaction table with just inserts is easier for financial auditing.

> Should the balance be stored physically or should it be calculated (considering that it might be updated with cron jobs)?

The balance should be stored physically.  It's much faster than calculating the balance by reading all of the transaction rows every time you need it.

Comment: ok it is true that inserts would be easier, but don't you think that there is a lot of redundency in the database? And wouldn't that lose distinction between operations?

I agree about storing the current balance. Although it may not have the latest and current value, but as I mentioned, there is room for leniency.

Answer (score 0):

I am IT student that has passed a course called databases, pardon my inexperience.

I made this using MySQL workbench can send you model via email to you do not lose time recreating the model from picture.

This schema was made in 10 minutes. Its holding transactions for a common shop.

[image]
Schema explanation
I have a person who can have multiple phones and addresses. 
Person makes transactions when he is making a transaction,

- You input card name e.g. american express, 
  card type credit or debit (MySQL workbench does not have domains or constrains as power-designer as far as i know so i left field type as varchar) should have limited input of string debit or credit,
- Card expiry date e.g. 8/12,
- Card number e.g. 1111111111
- Amount for which to decrease e.g. 20.0
- time-stamp of transaction
  program enters it when entering data
- And link it to person that has made the transsaction
  via person_idperson field.
  e.g.
  1

While id 1 in table person has name John Smith

What all this offers:

1. transaction is uniquely using a card. Credit or Debit cant be both cant be none.
2. Speed less table joins more speed for system has.

What program requires:

1. Continuous comparion of fields variable exactTimestamp is less then variable cardExpiery when entering a transaction.
2. Constant entering of card details.

Whats system does not have

1. Saving amount that is used in the special field, however that can be accomplished with Sql query
2. Saving amount that remains, I find that a personal information, What I mean is you come to the shop and shopkeeper asks me how much money do you still have?
3. system does not tie person to the card explicitly. 
   The person must be present and use the card with card details, and keeping anonymity of the person. (Its should be a query complex enough not to type by hand by an amateur e.g. shopkeeper) , if i want to know which card person used last time i get his last transaction and extract card fields.

I hope you think of this just as a proposition.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but I think that you misunderstood something in that each Credit operation has an expiry, not the whole account. So I have to keep track of which Credit transaction has expired, and from which credit operation(s) this Debit transaction has been completed. Did I miss something?

Comment: here credit operation = transaction, debit operation = transaction difference is in field card_type. A program that will be written for the serve your database can get current time compare it to time-stamp of transaction which have type of credit, the comparison of those to create expiry. Than you have some method like if current date compared to date in time-stamp field > e.g. 1 month then paint the string showing the transaction red. debit transactions are completed on when you make transaction, you can put a Boolean field transaction table marking completion of the transaction.